# Can't retrieve HTTP Response Cookie - Angular 2 CORS

Tags: angular, tomcat, cookies, httprequest, cross-domain

Im having trouble with accessing a http response's cookies. According to Postman, it is getting sent as shown here: 
[image]

And this is what the requests looks like according to Google Chrome's network developer tab:
[Google Chrome's Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ4X6.png)

Here is the code that I use to send the get request:

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers, user:String, pass:String) {
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
    btoa(user+":"+pass));
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

login() {
  var user = this.username.nativeElement.value;
  var pass = this.password.nativeElement.value;

  let header = new Headers();
  this.createAuthorizationHeader(header, user, pass);
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header, withCredentials: true });

  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/sample-webapp/rest/auth/login', options)
  .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.headers.get('Set-Cookie'));
  });
}
```

After looking it up for a while, withCredentials: true was supposed to fix my issue and include the cookie in the response header. But all I get is this:
[image]

It doesn't seem like a backend issue cause the cookie is received by the Browser and Postman. Please let me know what I can do to get my yummy cookies?

Also the backend has the following headers:

```
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeaderString("origin"));
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeaderString("access-control-request-headers"));
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", request.getHeaderString("access-control-request-method"));
```

Comment: Did you get to solve it ?

Comment: Please let me know if you ever solved it. I am not able to retrieve Set-Cookie header in the response.